# perl regex parenthesis matching

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a variable `$next` which contains strings that might contain parenthesis e.g `trna(tgc)` I want to make this matching statement `if ($data[$i][2]=~/$next/){ ..}` and it always return false even if it's true in reality. I tried this `if ($data[$i][2]=~/trnA\(tgc\)/){ ..}`and it works. 
my question is : how to insert the '\' in front of each parenthesis into the variable `$next`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
$next = "trna(tgc)";
$search = quotemeta($next);
if ($data[$i][2]=~/$search/){ 
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote meta-characters.

Try this.

```
print "match" if( $var1 =~ /\Q$var2\E/ );
```